# iPhone voicemail malfunction

Tags: iphone, voicemail

The voicemail on my iPhone used to work well, so basically if I click the `voicemail` button on the interface of `Phone`app, I would get a list of voicemail that I can choose from and listen to.

But recently, I found that whenever I click the voicemail button, I was transferred to a call as shown below and it looks pretty much like a virus to me.

> Click the voicemail button on the lower right corner,

[image]

> You will be automatically transferred to a call,

[image]

Is this a virus or some mis-configuration of my iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reboot the phone.
If no better ring your provider.

Mine did that after I changed my phone contract [with the same provider, just a different plan] & they had to reset it from their end.

Comment: Solved my problem, basically I have to reset the password for my voicemail after upgrading my plan. Not a virus.

Comment: @Nicholas [It's *definitely* not a virus](https://www.xkcd.com/1180/).  Before [visual voicemail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_voicemail) (or even now on carriers which don't support it), voicemail on a cell phone was accessed by dialing a specific number and using the keypad to select menu options.  Your phone most likely failed to load visual voicemail, so it fell back to dialing the voicemail number.

Comment: Very funny and informative!@NobodyNada